# How can i get the ContentType of a ajax request in plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I have a script that  sends an AJAX request to a server and if the answer is just text it is gonna put it in a div but if its json it should handle it different.

```js
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        document.body.innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
};
xhttp.open(method, "/controller.php?url=" + location, true);
xhttp.send(data);
```

now how can i check if `xhttp.responeText` is json?

Comment: This sounds odd. An API endpoint should have a predictable content type, either/or, not sometimes this, sometimes that. Usually this is done by _always_ returning a JSON structure which contains a different payload type indicated by properties inside the structure.

Comment: Always returning json would work, but i still want to know if it is possible to do this. Because otherwise i would have to rewrite quite some code, which i dont want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript you can can use **getResponseHeader('content-type')** method to check the content type of returned JSON response

```js
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        if(this.getResponseHeader('content-type') == 'application/json'){
             //do something with the json
        }
        else{
             document.body.innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
};
xhttp.open(method, "/controller.php?url=" + location, true);
xhttp.send(data);
```

In Jquery you can try something like this

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "www.yourURL.com", 
  data: "data which you want to sent to server", 
  success: function(response, status, xhr){ 
    var ct = xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type") || "";
    if (ct.indexOf('text') > -1) {
      //do something
    }
    if (ct.indexOf('json') > -1) {
      // handle json here
    } 
  }
});
```

Basically it will check the string 'html' or 'json' exist in the response header

Comment: this is JQuery but i asked for plain javascript because i dont want to include big librarys i barely use

Comment: mistake from my side ..will post another answer for the same